# Pie Chart Vega Lite : Conditional Slice colors

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I would like the pie slices to be colored with the PowerBI scheme color except for the "other players" section which needs to be always grey.

[My Pbx link]https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv6jnMWzcGS6aWvMr9?e=kEt8cY

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "Points_calculation",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": true
    },
    "order": {
      "field": "ORDER",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Name",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {
        "field": "ORDER",
        "order": "descending"
      },
      "legend": null, 
       "scale": {"scheme": "pbiColorNominal"}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "******RING BACKGROUND******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": 100
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": 100, "fill":{"expr":"datum.Name =='Other players'?'grey':''"}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Name labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 115,
        "dy" : 4,
        "fill": "black",
        "align": {
          "expr": "scale('theta', datum.Points_calculation_end) > PI ?'right':'left'"
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Name",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Values_Labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 80,
        "fill": "black"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Points_calculation",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Formidable ! Nice trick to cover the "Other" section by a one in grey !